# Google Spread Sheet Script. Working with Dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am reading list of Google Sheet cells containing DateTime, using Google Apps Script.
The values in the cells are:

**A1: Jul 26 13:00**

**A2: Jul 27 0:00**

```
var dateValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A2").getValues();
```

However, values read are 1 hour behind. This is what I see in the debugger:

dateValues[0] = Wed Jul 26 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)

dateValues[1] = Wed Jul 26 2017 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)

I guess this is a time zone issue, but I don't really understand the concept.
My time zone is **currently** (due to DTS) GMT + **3**. Indeed, outside the DTS period it is GMT +2. The spread sheet time zone is Jerusalem GMT+2.

EET - don't underrated why it is being used.

Basically, I would expect to get in code the values with in the sheet.

What is the concept?

Comment: In the spreadsheet itself, under File->Spreadsheet settings, what is the Time zone set to?

Comment: @Karl_S Jerusalem GMT + 2

Comment: Can you change it to your time zone and see what you get?

Comment: @Karl_S Maybe I was not clear enough. Sorry. It is my time zone.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to solved this

1. Use **getDisplayValues**() rather than **getValues**(). This will force to do some conversions, as **getDisplayValues**() returns strings not dates
2. make you script editor time zone match the sheet tz.
   In my case the sheet was (GMT+2 Jerusalem), but the script editor was different (GMT+2 Moscow) for some reason.
   Setting the script editor TZ, solved the problem.